# Virtuemart's product's images rename

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I have a quite large eshop built with Joomla 1.5.24 and Virtuemart
Is it possible to make all the pictures of categories and products have names like the categoriy's or product's name.
E.g
Category: Cars
Images: Cars.png
Thumb : Cars_thumb.png

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use phpMyAdmin to edit one product/category manually with the new image URL and copy the SQL statement replacing the `WHERE someID = X`..

Once you have prepared your SQL statements, execute them all in one go.

Of course, backup your database and *test test test*